# Get latest "x.png" from a folder

Tags: vb.net, random, directory, screenshot

I have a "take a screenshot" feature in my program. I am taking the screenshot and saving it with this code:

```
Bmp.Save(dir & "\MyApp\Screenshot" & random & ".png")
```

dir is Documents. and the random is this

```
random = CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 99999)) + 1
```

But I don't want to save like this. I want to save in order. I want to check the folder, get the latest name and add +1 to it. Like If the latest one is Screenshot-17.png, save it as Screenshot-18.png.

I am thinking a substring but I don't know how can I get the latest png file from a folder.

Full code is here:

```
    Dim dir As String
    dir = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
    Dim random As Integer
    random = CInt(Math.Ceiling(Rnd() * 99999)) + 1
    Dim pathh As String
    pathh = dir & "\MyApp\"
    If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(pathh)) Then
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathh)
    End If


    Dim Bmp As New Bitmap(WebControl1.ClientRectangle.Width, WebControl1.ClientRectangle.Height)
    Dim gBmp As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Bmp)
    gBmp.CopyFromScreen(WebControl1.PointToScreen(New Point(0, 0)), New Point(0, 0), New Size(WebControl1.Width, WebControl1.Height))
    Bmp.Save(dir & "\MyApp\Screenshot" & random & ".png")


    NotifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(1500, "Click here to see your screenshot!", "Saved to Documents/MyApp/Screenshot" & random & ".png!", ToolTipIcon.Info)
    baloon = pathh & "Screenshot" & random & ".png"
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? SO is for actual problems with actual code. You have no code here.

Comment: Still haven't posted any code that attempts to do what it is that you want to do.  If you haven't actually tried to do what it is that you want to do then you shouldn't be posting a question here at all.  Start by writing out what your logic needs to be and then research whatever topics that brings up.  We're not here as a substitute for your making an effort on your own behalf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Dim f As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("yourFolderLocation")
Dim files = f.GetFiles.ToList
Dim latest = (From file In files Select file Order By file.CreationTime Ascending).FirstOrDefault
```

Comment: `Ascending` will give you the first file not the last

Comment: @un-lucky:- OP can change it to descending(*its not that difficult*). The logic is important.

Answer (score 0):

better option for this scenario is this:

```
Dim newFileNMame As String = (Date.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "-" & TimeOfDay.ToString("HH-mm-ss"))
Bmp.Save(dir & "\MyApp\Screenshot\" & newFileNMame & ".png")
```

or else you will get the last file name by using the code below:

```
   Dim x As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo("D:\\TestFolder")
   Dim lastfileName = x.GetFileSystemInfos().OrderByDescending(Function(f) f.CreationTime).FirstOrDefault().Name
```

Comment: Yeah I did think about this but this is a game client and people would like to take a lotta screenshots. It will be bit confusing. However If I can't find a answer for my problem, I am going to use this.